# Local Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory, locality

When I read the paper ["Chaos and complexity by design"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04903), I found the following sentence in the Introduction part confusing:

> $$W(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^j}{j!}\underbrace{[H,\dots[H}_{j},W\underbrace{]\dots]}_{j}$$
>
> If $H$ is $q$-local and sufficiently “generic” to contain all possible $q$-local interactions, then the $j$th term will consist of a sum of roughly ∼ $(n/q)^{qj}$ terms each of weight ranging from 1 to ∼ $j(q − 1)$, where we assume the system consists of n spins so that the Hilbert space is of dimension $d = 2n$."

But I have no idea why the sum of terms would be $(n/q)^{qj}$ and why the weight would range from 1 to ~$j(q-1)$. I guess $(n/q)$ may refer to the number of interaction terms in the Hamiltonian, since n refers to the number of spins and q means q-local. But then I do not know where the exponent qj comes from.

Actually I am also confused about what "terms" actually means here and the concept "q-local Hamiltonian"(I guess it just means a Hamiltonian containing many terms of interactions, each of which includes less than q local operators)

Comment: And maybe who can tell me how to type a formula in PhysicsStackExchange? I am new here, thanks :)

Comment: MathJax, a LaTeX variant, is enabled here. For an overview of available commands, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I guess that "local" in this context refers to nearest neighbours. Then $q$-local might refer to the $q$-nearest neighbours.

Comment: @FraSchelle Do you know how to count the number of terms in the Hamiltonian? I think your guess makes sense, but I have trouble counting the terms to match the result in the paper. I only know how to count it in the case of 2-local Hamiltonian like that in the 1-d Ising model ...

Comment: Well, $j(q-1)$ is clear : at order $j$ you get $j$ Hamiltonians in the expansion, each of them has about $q$ neighbours interaction. The term with $n$ might be a count of number of degrees of freedom maybe... Perhaps there is an indication of the nature of the interaction somewhere else in the paper, which helps doing such a count.

Comment: @FraSchelle Sorry I am still confused where $j(q-1)$ comes. There are $j$ Hamiltonians, but they are multiplied instead of being added. Maybe I got something wrong?